# Is this the right way to write OOP PDO classes?

Tags: php, object-oriented, pdo

I have just begun to work with OOP and I am converting my current project into OOP classes. I have a few questions about this `User` class.

```
class User {
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db, $utilities) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->utilities = $utilities;
    }

    function set_user($input) {
        check if user exists and if yes set
        $this->user = $userid;
    }   

    function info() {
        return user info
    }

    function awards() {
        return user awards
    }
}
```

I am wondering if this is the correct approach, and how should this be used. When a user is logged in I have a `$logged_in = new User;` variable set and then I go about setting the user and pulling required variables. When we get on certain pages there are specific sections that have `foreach` statements that display other users and their awards. Do I create a new instance of class `User` in each `foreach` or do I create one instance of the class and use that everywhere needed?

This project is a CMS and on nearly every page it displays multiple areas containing user info. I am wondering what the best way to do this is.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately, this code doesn't seem to be ready for review because it does not appear to be finished. Code Review is for making *completed and working* code better.

Comment: If every user will be fetch from the same db I whould put $db static instead of private

Answer (score 2):

If a `User` object represents a single User, you would want one `User` instance per actual user you are working with in the application. For example, say your user might have friends:

```
class User {
    private $friends;

    public function addFriend(User $friend) {
        if (!in_array($friend, $this->friends)) {
            $this->friends[] = $friend;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, your `User` object can hold an array of other `User` objects, who he's friends with! You can do all sorts of cool stuff with that, like listing mutual friends (since those Users have their `$friends` array too!), displaying a list of friends on the page, or just figuring out who has more friends.

The `User` object is commonly known as a **Domain** object, it's an object which is part of the **Domain Logic** or **Business Logic**, i.e. the actual application, the actual purpose of the application, the part that does the actual work.

---

### Review:

- Most naming conventions in PHP dictate that `$variableNames` should be camelCased and not lowercase_underscores, however, stick with that works for you, and don't break existing convention if you're working in a collaborative project.
- It's often preferable to **separate** the part where the User's details are kept and actual computation and processing takes place, and the part which is responsible for **fetching and saving** the User's details from permanent storage of some sort.

Consider this:

```
class User {
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct($id, $name) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

This User object is different, **it doesn't know where the details come from**, they are injected from that magical place outside of the object where it doesn't know anything about. This User could have come from a database, he could have come from session, a file, a REST api, or I could have just made it up for testing purposes.

So how do you get the details from the database? You use the **[Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)** pattern.

```
class UserMapper {

    public function __construct(PDO $db_connection) {
        $this->db = $db_connection;
    }

    /** 
      * Fetch user details from the database based on ID.
      * If $user exists, fill it. If not, create a new one.
      */
    public function fetch($id, User $user = null) { ... }
    /**
      * Save $user back into the database
      */
    public function save(User $user) { ... }

    ....
}
```

You can have more methods like "fetch the N top user with most comments", or "Fetch all the friends of this $user"

The point is, the `Mapper` is responsible for getting/saving all necessary data from the database *or whatever other permanent storage you might need*, and fill the actual Domain Object, which is then used by the application to do processing.

Comment: In this context the fetch should be: `fetch(User $user, $id = null)`, because, if ou decide to pull out the `$id`, then you should compensate for other `UNIQUE` constraint based queries (like `$user->getEmail()`).